# VSTO ColumnChanging event not fired and HasChanges not working correctly on Excel sheet

Tags: c#, windows-7, ado.net, vsto, excel-2007

Some background: there is an VSTO plugin to Excel written in c#, .net 4.0
Excel has many tabs that are filled with data from database using DataSets. When users add data to sheet some columns are automatically set with default data. We're using HasChanges methods of DataSet to check if there were modifications in data and highlight them.

Generally it works pretty well. But we have a strange issue on one of users station. The ColumnChanging event is not fired. Additionally DataSet.HasChanges method is returning false even if the new data is added.

The problem only occurs on Windows 7 machine with Excel 2007 installed.

We tried to reproduce the problem on DEV machines (Windows XP, Excel 2007) by disabling macros but without success. We can't install Visual Studio on user machine obviously.

Do you have any ideas how to reproduce and fix it? Maybe it is configuration issue?

Comment: First is the piece of code that modifies Dataset get executed? can you share some code?

Comment: @BrijeshMishra DataSet is modified by user in excel. I think that it may be related to some user configuration - other users don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Application.SheetChange, it can be more reliable

UPD when you deal with wrapped COM object and subscribe to an event of it, you need to keep a reference to original object to keep it alive (event subscription is not enough)

Answer (score 1):

Client suggestions:

- Possible security settings on client.
- Is there an installer? If so, try uninstalling then re-installing.
- Also, get the debugger from the SDK. You may be able to use on client machine depending on your build settings, configuration settings, and if you deployed the pdb.
- Have you repaired .NET 4.0 on client?
- Have you repaired VSTO 4 Run-time on client? Also there is a required update to VSTO 4 Run-time.

Code suggestions:

- The most likely cause for an event not firing, is the object changes and the reference to the event is lost. Make sure the data set never changes.
- Make sure there the event handlers have not been removed.
- Possible there is an error causing the data-set variable to be reset and event lost.
- Possible disposing then creating another instance.

Comment: I suspect that problem lies somewhere in security settings because on other stations everything is working well. Problems only appear on 2 Windows 7 machines. We'll also check the .NET 4.0 & VSTO installations.